# R DT package add trailing zeros to align decimal

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I'm trying to format a table in a shiny app. I'm using the `datatable` function in the DT package. I have columns with values like `xxx.yyy, x.y, x.yyyyy, x`. I'd like to format these as `xxx.yy, x.y0, x.yy, x.00`. The formatRound('colName', 'digits') function takes care of xxx.yyy (formatRound(x = xxx.yyy, 2) but doesn't add the trailing zero(s).

The formatRound (and other format* functions in DT) are wrappers for some javascript code. Is there some addition to this code that would pad with zeros?

Comment: I think I can help but can you please ask with a [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1422451) code/data per the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [`r`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info) tag description?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My default function for this is `sprintf`, and it works like this:

```
sprintf(mtcars$mpg, fmt="%#.2f")
```

The `2` specifies digits after the decimal.

```
[1] "21.00" "21.00" "22.80" "21.40" ...
```

Comment: And if you want to align on the decimal this code does the trick. It does right align, but since all numbers have the same number of digits after the decimal, that also means the decimal is aligned.  `columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-right', targets = 3:5)) # Note target numbers start at column 0, so this does columns 4 to 6`.